# Log Shipping with Failover Cluster Server Cores

Tags: sql-server, clustering, log-shipping, sql-server-core, windows-server

- Failover Over Cluster 2 Node - 6 Cores- Enterprise Edition 2014
- Log Shipping with Cluster with 4 Core License- Enterprise Edition 2014

My question is if I need to log ship do I need to match the server core of the Primary server that is the failover cluster (6 core) in my case or I can go with 4 core on the Log Shipped server to save licensing costs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you don't need to match hardware. There's no technical requirement for that.

Lots of people choose to use slightly less robust hardware at DR

1. Saves on licensing costs
2. Offloaded reads may not need full production power
3. Assume that DR failovers aren't permanent

That said, whatever lower tier of hardware you choose has to be able to support your current workload.

In general, you want to make sure you're not hitting any really bad resource waits like `THREADPOOL` -- if you're hitting it on 6 cores, you'll definitely hit it on 4 cores.

If you have less RAM at DR, be aware of `RESOURCE_SEMAPHORE` waits.

The only way to tell for sure is to coordinate a failover and measure your server's response to your workload.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Great Explanation. Thanks a lot. Much Appreciated.